# How to capture a image in Android OpenCV

Tags: android, image, opencv, image-processing, camera

I am working in a project of Image processing and now I have one issue where I imported the OpenCV library I converted the RGB frame to binary frame. Now I dont know how to capture the binary image and store it in database. There is no tutorial available regarding the OpenCV library. So could any one please help me to solve the issue. My coding is below..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener,CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getCanonicalName();
private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
private Mat mRgba;
private Scalar mBlobColorHsv;
private Scalar mBlobColorRgba;

private Mat mIntermediateMat;
private Mat mGray;
Mat hierarchy;


List<MatOfPoint> contours;


private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback=new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                mOpenCvCameraView.setOnTouchListener(MainActivity.this);
            }
            break;
            default: {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
            break;

        }
    }

};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


    mOpenCvCameraView=(CameraBridgeViewBase)findViewById(R.id.opencv_tutorial_activity_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(mOpenCvCameraView!=null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    {
        super.onResume();
        if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_2, this, mLoaderCallback);
        }
        else{
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onPause();
    if(mOpenCvCameraView!=null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    return false;
}


@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mRgba=new Mat();
    mBlobColorRgba=new Scalar(255);
    mBlobColorHsv=new Scalar(255);
    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mIntermediateMat = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mGray = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    hierarchy = new Mat();
}
```

So in short what I want to do is create a button and in onclick method I want to capture the image and preview of the image has to be displayed. Please someone help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In short you want to convert a Mat to a Bitmap?

Comment: Actually you were right but I want to capture a image using a button. I dont know how to do it. Could you please help me with the coding part how to do it.

Comment: I've posted an edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to preview the image then you have to convert the mat to a bitmap and then display it in an ImageView. You can set a CvCameraViewListener to receive the bitmap. Like so

```
    private Mat mat;
    private boolean showPreviews;
        private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback=new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
            @Override
            public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
                switch (status) {
                    case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                        Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                      someButton.setOnclickListener(new View.OnclickListener(View v){
                               showPreviews = !showPreviews;
});
                        mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                        mOpenCvCameraView.setOnTouchListener(MainActivity.this);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(MainActivity.this);

                    }
                    break;
                    default: {
                        super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    }
                    break;

                }
            }

        };

        @Override
            public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public void onCameraViewStopped() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               if(!showPreviews)
      mat = inputFrame.rgba();
           // you can return a modified mat if you want to display it in opencv
                return mat;
            }
```

Comment: Yes. You were right. But what I want is there is a button "click me". If I touch the button the image should be captured and then it should be displayed. So now when I do just as you told me I was not able to capture the image and also displayPreview method was never used. Sorry for the inconvinience, being a beginner I was not about to grasp the answer that you provide me. If you dont mind could you please be more specific and resolve my issue.

Comment: I've updated the answer for you to easily understand.

Comment: Awesome. Your program works great. Its working. But unfortunately I am stuck with some other situation. Being a fresher and working in a OpenCv library it is too hard to understand the concept and work in it. If you dont mind can you please help me in this OpenCv library to finish this application and guide me to finish this job. I need some proper guidance to learn this and work in this. If you are free and ready to help me please do ping me in this mail Id: someshwaran23@gmail.com. Thanks a lot for your guidance.

Comment: Okay, I've sent you an email.